# MySQL: I need to SUM after GROUP BY the records

Tags: mysql

I have this query and subquery, and I wonder if it is possible to avoid using the subquery.

As you can see, I need to sum the maxium value between the points scored by a user on a single day, and 100.
And later, I need to sum the total points done on all days.

```
    SELECT sum(daily_points) as total
        FROM (
            SELECT LEAST(SUM(points.value), 100) AS daily_points
            FROM points
            WHERE user_id = 1234
            AND points.type = 'bonus'
            GROUP BY DATE(points.created)
        ) AS points_sum;
```

I don't know if it is possible to do it on a single query, as I need to group the registers before, and sum it later.

Also, I have tried using ROLLUP on the subquery, but it doesn't work because I have to sum the points done in one day only if those are not higher than 100.

Thank you all in advance for your help.

Comment: Perhaps ROLLUP , https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1):

The subquery is the correct approach here, I'm afraid.